# Looping through a list of data frames and parsing the data frame name to retrieve values for new columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of data frames (created by reading each of the files in a directory); each data frame contains 4 columns:

```
hit_name  (character)
hit_raw_value (real)
hit_norm_value (real)
hit_significance (real)
```

In addition I want to add 3 columns to each data frame, called -- drugname, dose and group. The value of each column in a particular data frame would be identical across all rows and is obtainable from parsing the name of that data frame, which is of the format: "drugname_dose_group_date_studyname". For example, one data frame is called "tylenol_5mg_group1_oct14_pilotstudy", so the 'drugname' column that I want to add would take the value 'tylenol', the 'dose' column would take the value '5mg', and the group column would take the value 'group1'.

The code below that I tried out lands up setting x$drugname to a string containing the names of all the already existing columns in that data frame, rather than setting it to 'drugname'.

```
all_files = lapply(paste(mydir,filenames,sep="") ,read.delim) 
names(all_files) = gsub(".txt","", filenames)
lapply( all_files,
     function(x) {
         x$drugname = gsub(".+?\\_(.+?)\\_(.+?)\\_(.+?)\\_.+", "\\1", deparse(quote(x)))   
         x$dose = gsub(".+?\\_(.+?)\\_(.+?)\\_(.+?)\\_.+", "\\2", deparse(quote(x)))        
         x$group = gsub(".+?\\_(.+?)\\_(.+?)\\_(.+?)\\_.+", "\\3", deparse(quote(x)))
}
```

Comment: Please tidy up this question and show the exact structure of your data frames and input.

Comment: you can use `dput` to paste a small reproducible example of your dataset

Comment: `deparse(quote(x))` is not likely going to work inside a `lapply`

Answer (score 0):

`deparse(quote(x))` returns `x` inside the lapply because the variable x is defined.

Can you try instead this

```
for (i in names(all_files)){
    newCols = strsplit(names(all_files)[i], "_")[[1]]
    all_files[[i]]$drugname = newCols[1]
    all_files[[i]]$dose     = newCols[2]
    ...
}
do.call(rbind, all_files)
```

Comment: Thanks very much -- that worked very nicely, with a minor modification to the strsplit function call. I paste the final code version below.

Comment: @BioBos indeed I forgot to specify the "_" ... Thanks for that. I made my answer a community wiki one so that you can edit it. I do not recommend to use `unlist` as it does not guarantee the order, but rather selecting the first element of the string split using `[[1]]`

Answer (score 0):

This snippet of code worked for looping through the names of the dataframes and populating the new $drugname and $dose columns appropriately, thank you for the help:

```
for (i in names(all_files)){
  newCols = unlist(strsplit(names(all_files)[i], "_"))
  all_files[[i]]$drugname = newCols[1]
  all_files[[i]]$dose     = newCols[2]
  ...
}
```